# Is Weissman score for compression valid?

Tags: algorithm, compression, lossless-compression

Is there is really something like weissmann score given as per the efficiency to compress something as shown in "Silicon Valley" TV Series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The show sparked the creation of an official score for lossless compression called the Weissman Score which was developed by a professor at Stanford as well as a graduate student. Here is some more reading that can be done on it.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weissman_score

and

http://spectrum.ieee.org/view-from-the-valley/computing/software/a-madefortv-compression-metric-moves-to-the-real-world

Comment: Official according to which authority? All the citations only speak of the "potential" of this score (or don't mention it at all).

Comment: Additionally, I'd like to point out that the formula for the Weissman Score is complete bunk. Unless time is being measured in microseconds or smaller, then it's trivial to get an infinite score: simply return the input as-is, then wait for one time unit to pass. You could even add an arbitrary amount of garbage data to the end of the file, and still be the "perfect" compression algorithm according to the Weissman Score.